# Vite Dev mode works but serving the build does not work. n2.BigInt is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, config, vite, turborepo

So I'm using vite for my project which is a monorepo setup using turborepo. There are no problems while using dev mode or building the project, however when I serve the project I'm getting the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n2.BigInt is not a function`. Can someone please help why the dev mode and build mode work differently for vite?

Putting my config below

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    viteTsconfigPaths(),
    svgrPlugin(),
    legacy(),
    commonjs(),
    nodePolyfills({ protocolImports: true }),
  ],
  optimizeDeps: {
    esbuildOptions: {
      target: "es2020", // Enable Big integer literals
      define: {
        global: "globalThis",
      },
      supported: {
        bigint: true,
      },
    },
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      assert: "assert",
      buffer: "buffer",
      crypto: "crypto-browserify",
      http: "stream-http",
      https: "https-browserify",
      os: "os-browserify/browser",
      process: "process/browser",
      stream: "stream-browserify",
      util: "util",
      "~@fontsource": "@fontsource",
    },
  },
  server: {
    open: true,
    port: 3000,
  },
  build: {
    minify: false,
    target: "es2020", // Enable Big integer literals
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true, // Enable @walletconnect/web3-provider which has some code in CommonJS
    },

    rollupOptions: {
      // maxParallelFileOps: 2,
      cache: false,
    },
    outDir: "build",
  },
});
```

I tried changing the vite config with different settings for rollup and esbuildoptions but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `target` from `ESNext` to `es2020` due to  `BigInt` not being available in `ESNext`.

```
build: {
    minify: false,
    target: "es2020", 
    commonjsOptions: {
      transformMixedEsModules: true, // Enable @walletconnect/web3-provider which has some code in CommonJS
    },

    rollupOptions: {
      // maxParallelFileOps: 2,
      cache: false,
    },
    outDir: "build",
  },
```

Add this to your `tsconfig` file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020", "esnext"
    ],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
}
```

Comment: I tried it, still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: Could you try the modified answer? I think that might work

Comment: So settings the module as commonjs is bringing on more issues in vite, for example the import.meta.env doesn't work anymore. and the issue still remains. the other app in the monorepo serves absolutely fine with the same config, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

The latest issues are caused by a Uniswap package dependancy, you need to polyfill JSBI

answer here [Vite app works in DEV but not after BUILD and PREVIEW BigInt is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77769749/vite-app-works-in-dev-but-not-after-build-and-preview-bigint-is-not-a-function)